# can not get the right number of columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have imported a table to my database, and to get the number of columns and assign it to a variable I do

```
SELECT @HowManyColumns = COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
 WHERE (TABLE_NAME = @table_name )
```

But it keeps telling that the count is 0!

If I do the same for other tables it works!

I have found that the column count of the table that is not working is more than 40 columns, Why is it not working...
[The data is this](http://www.eurekavianstudios.com/waveform.txt)

Comment: What if you check [via SYS.COLUMNS](http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server/sys.columns_Getting_a_List_of_Columns_in_a_Table.html)?

Comment: nope, I still do not get anything, It is making me crazy, Why sometimes it work, and some does not

Comment: `@table_name` doesn't have any surrounding brackets or double qoutes, does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since tables w/o columns don't exists, that can only mean that the WHERE clause is not satisfied. In other words, the table named as the value of @table_name does not exists. Since you say 'sometimes it work, and some does not' that would immediately point toward case sensitive deployments. Make sure you **always** use the correct name for the table, with the proper case, so your code work correctly on servers which are deployed with a case sensitive collation.

Answer (score 1):

Try issuing 
     SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA

and check table name for case.

Answer (score 1):

Try having the table name as a text string instead:

```
DECLARE 
    @table_name varchar(50),
    @noOfColumns int
SET 
    @table_name = 'table_name'
SET
    @noOfColumns =
        (SELECT count(*)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name)

PRINT @noOfColumns
```

The answer you get is the number of columns in the @noOfColumns variable